# Why access_token becomes invalid

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

what are the reasons that the access_token instagram becomes invalid. I've noticed that there is no time expiration of the token?

Does someone know how to avoid it?

thanks a lot for your replies

Answer (score 0):

Your all answers are given here in this document:

https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

> Important 
>   Even though our access tokens do not specify an expiration
>   time, your app should handle the case that either the user revokes
>   access, or Instagram expires the token after some period of time. If
>   the token is no longer valid, API responses will contain an
>   “error_type=OAuthAccessTokenException”. In this case you will need to
>   re-authenticate the user to obtain a new valid token. In other words:
>   do not assume your access_token is valid forever.

So Token expire in two case

- User revoke access
- After some time (No specific time interval)

**Does someone know how to avoid it?**

No. Ther is no way to avoid it because that is for security reason. Avoiding it is compromising the security of the user and Instagram definitely don't want that.

So the only solution (And proper way) is to handle `OAuthAccessTokenException`